# Scraping data from a web using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from the below web page:

http://www.bigpara.com/borsa/gecmis-kapanislar/endeks/14-aralik-2015
The related source is:

```
<div class="tableCnt">
    <div class="table wide">
        <div class="tableBox">
            <div class="tHead">
                <ul>
                    <li class="cell008 tal">Menkul Adı</li>
                    <li class="cell002">Dün</li>
                    <li class="cell002">1.Seans</li>
                    <li class="cell002">2.Seans</li>
                    <li class="cell002">%</li>
                    <li class="cell002">Yüksek</li>
                    <li class="cell002">Düşük</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tBody">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="cell008 tal arrow"><a href="/borsa/endeksler/bist-30-agirlik-sinirlamali-endeksi/">X030S</a></li>
                            <li class="cell002">86.337</li>
                            <li class="cell002">87.403</li>
                            <li class="cell002">85.010</li>
                            <li class="cell002">-1,54</li>
                            <li class="cell002">88.151</li>
                            <li class="cell002">84.863</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="cell008 tal arrow"><a href="/borsa/endeksler/bist-100-agirlik-sinirlamali-endeksi/">X100S</a></li>
                            <li class="cell002">70.274</li>
                            <li class="cell002">71.146</li>
                            <li class="cell002">69.302</li>
                            <li class="cell002">-1,38</li>
                            <li class="cell002">71.680</li>
```

I want to scrape 69.302.

[image]

This example is just for this date(14-aralik-2015/14-December-2015). However I will make a loop to scrape the same cell for other dates.

I tried a lot of things but web scraping seems to me so difficult. I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rvest` makes this pretty easy. For a single cell, just use right-click, inspect, then copy the xpath for the cell. Something tells me you are going to change your question and ask for more than this single cell though...

```
library("rvest")
url <- "http://www.bigpara.com/borsa/gecmis-kapanislar/endeks/14-aralik-2015/2-ocak-2000"

read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[4]') %>% 
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()
```

Comment: The code gives error for me as below as 'Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "read_html' . And you are right:) I will edit it.

Comment: You need to `install.packages("rvest")` and `library("rvest")` before you attempt to run the code.

Comment: An alternative CSS selector: `".tBody ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(4)"`

Comment: The problem was version of rvest @cory. I updated it and your code worked. Thanks a lot.